# Removing Subview/UILabel after reloading view

Tags: ios, json, reachability

I added a UILabel to my view whenever there's no internet connection (using Reachablity).

```
UILabel *pullLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 50, 290, 30)];
pullLabel.text = @"Pull down to refresh...";
pullLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.view addSubview:pullLabel];
```

I want to get rid of label after the view gets refreshed (with uirefreshcontrol).
I tried adding `removeFromSuperview` and hiding the label but I still can't get it to work.

```
if ([self.refreshControl isRefreshing]) {
   [self.pullLabel removeFromSuperview];
   [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

My viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.soleresource.com"];

    reach.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability *reachability)
    {
        [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

        [[self navigationItem] setPrompt: nil]; // Hide navigation prompt
        [self.pullLabel removeFromSuperview];
    };

    reach.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability *reachability)
    {
        self.navigationItem.prompt = @"No internet connection available";

        UILabel *pullLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 50, 290, 30)];
        pullLabel.text = @"Pull down to refresh...";
        pullLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [self.view addSubview:pullLabel];
    };

    [reach startNotifier];

    self.upcomingReleases = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self makeReleasesRequests];

    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(makeReleasesRequests) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.collectionView addSubview:_refreshControl];
    self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: why not just set hidden to yes or set alpha to 0.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put pullLabel into self.pullLabel.  self.pullLabel is nil when you are calling removeFrom Superview.

```
self.pullLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 50, 290, 30)];
self.pullLabel.text = @"Pull down to refresh...";
self.pullLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:self.pullLabel];
```